# Why SharedPreferences doesn't works inside a OnClick event?

Tags: java, android

A simple example that doesn't work:

```
Button btn_validate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_verify_validate);
    btn_validate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("CONFIG", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
        spe.putInt("GL_ID_CLASS", 34);
        spe.commit();`
    }
}
```

But if I put it in OnCreate, for example, thats works.

Comment: Are you sure the code in `onClick` is executed at all? Add a `Log.d(..)` statement and check logcat or set a breakpoint when debugging with Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, works. The problem is with SharedPreferences

Comment: I think your SharedPreferences not get context anything inside onclick. This mention at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences